# wpf mvvm datepicker textbox auto format

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

Is it possible to auto format user input date in the textbox of a datepicker?

I have the following code

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTodayHighlighted" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedDateFormat" Value="Short"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="CalendarStyle" Value="{DynamicResource DatePickerCalendarStyle}" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
 Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy', 
 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And in my view I have

```
<DatePicker Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="518,34,0,0" Name="DateThru" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" SelectedDate="{Binding DateThruSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding DateThruIsEnabled}" >
</DatePicker>
```

So two issues.
First
When I enter into textbox "030613" or "03062013" and tap through I am expecting it to be formated to "03/06/2013" in the textbox of the datpicker automatically.

Second I am expecting SelectedDate property is set to "03/06/2013". (if I pick a date from embedded calendar the SelectedDate binding works fine.)

My current code posted here does neither of the two.
Any idea how I can achieve the two goals?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About the first issue :**

Regex comes to my mind. For ease of use, try using some abstract class, and derive it, like :

```
public abstract class DateTimeRegexPattern
{
    public abstract DateTime DateTime { get; }

    public abstract bool IsMatch(string input);
}
```

For every pattern you want it be recognized, you derive that abstract class (could be enhanced), and put them in a list. Whenever the textbox's content changes, in order to detect which pattern could be applied, use LINQ.

```
List<DateTimeRegexPattern> patterns = new List<DateTimeRegexPattern>();
// Fill the list with one instance of each of derived classes of DateTimeRegexPattern
DateTimeRegexPattern matching = patterns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsMatch("030613"));
```

Then, retrieve the DateTime, if any pattern matches, and apply it to the DatePicker, *if the current Date is different.*

**About the second issue :**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddatechanged.aspx This event should do the trick. When the date changes, change the textbox's content, *if the dates are different.*

Comment: Hi, David, thanks for the reply. When I tried to format the typed-in date in the textbox I have no way to reach the DatePickerTextBox embedded in the DatePicker. So my number one issue becomes how to access the DatePickerTextBox embedded in the DatePicker.

Comment: Since you have two instance of class, there must be some place (the common parent) which have sight of both of them. Make the initialization required from there ?

Comment: I resolved it by getting the texbox from routedeventargs in the event handler. Thanks for the help.